# Symfony wont release the RAM it consumed, even after every thing is finished

Tags: mysql, apache, symfony1, doctrine, php-5.3

We have a symfony app which consume lot of RAM(8GB) and CPU as well. The problem is, even after everything is finished, it holds the memory without releasing. It will release the memory after rebooting the apache. 
In our app, We use Doctrine as the active record.
we would highly appreciate all of your performance enhancement tips.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony is not responsabile to memory release. That's what php gc do. Symfony is just a framework like any other. Not sure what you do in your app and end up using so much memory. Probably you're storing too much data in arrays...Symfony2 cache quite a lot in production so it's supposed to be quite fast.

I don't think any one will be able to help you cause your problem is very specific to your domain and not symfony2.